# Is $P+(I-P)C$ positive definite?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

$P=\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^T$($\mathbf{1}=[1,1,\dots,1]^T$), $I\in R^n$ is a indentity matrix, $C$ is a positive definite symmetric matrix. Is $P+(I-P)C$ positive definite? How to prove that?

With a random positive definite symmetric matrix $C$, I did 10 million experiments. All eigenvalues of $P+(I-P)C$ are with positive real parts.

Answer (score 2):

Note that even if the eigenvalues of this matrix is nonnegative, it will only be positive definite if
$$
P + (I-P)C
$$
is also symmetric. However, this is only the case when $P$ and $C$ commute, i.e., $[P,C] = 0$.

Here's a $2 \times 2$ counterexample
$$
P = \begin{pmatrix} 1/2 & 1/2 \\ 1/2 & 1/2 \end{pmatrix} \qquad C = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} 
$$
Then
$$
P + (I - P) C = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1/2 \\ 0 & 1/2 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Note this is not symmetric and so cannot be positive definite, it does however have positive eigenvalues $\{1, 1/2\}$.

Comment: The condition $[P, C]=0$ may be too strict here.

Comment: Why is it too strict? It is exactly what is required for it to be symmetric. If $(P + (I-P) C)^T = P+ (I-P) C$ then $ P^T + C^T (I - P^T) = P + (I-P) C$, which given the symmetric nature of the variables involved implies $P + C(I-P) = P + (I-P) C$ which implies $CP = PC$, i.e., $[P,C] = 0$.

Comment: I thought carefully about what you said. Yes, we may not be able to prove that the original problem is positive semi-definite. Since $P+(I−P)C$ may not be symmetric.

Comment: I modify the problem. Please see if the new problem can be proved. Thx~

Comment: @HaoWANG No it cannot, for exactly the same reasons... your matrix is not symmetric.